# Github actions for creating an npm pacakge from angular workspace/library

Tags: angular, github, npm, github-actions

[image]So I have this github action code, I'm trying to create a github package for diferent libraries in the workspace, The build step works fine however on the publish step I get this error `Error: Process completed with exit code 2.` dist folder doesnt exist it says.
Note the dist folder is created after the build process is completed and it is added .gitignore fire as well.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here.

```
name: Angular Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      release_type:
        required: false
        type: string
      project_name:
        description: 'Enter the project name'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install Angular CLI
        run: npm install -g @angular/cli
      
      - name: Install dependencies  
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build Angular Project
        run: ng build ${{ github.event.inputs.project_name }}
        

  debug:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: List Files in dist
        run: ls -R dist

      - name: Print Current Directory
        run: pwd

  publish:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        run: |
          cd dist/${{ github.event.inputs.project_name }}
          npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          npm publish --access public
          env:
            NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the yaml file I've come up with.
Note: Each run starts from the root folder.
Note: to carry items to the next job you've to upload artifactsand download them in the next job.

```
name: Angular Package

on:
  release:
   types: [created]
   workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
     project_name:
     description: 'Enter the project name'
     required: true
     type: string

jobs:
 build:
  permissions: write-all
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3
   - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
     with:
      node-version: 16
      registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/

   - name: Install Angular CLI
     run: npm install -g @angular/cli
  
  - name: Install dependencies  
    run: npm ci

  - name: Build Angular Project
    run: ng build ${{ github.event.inputs.project_name }}

  - name: Upload Artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: build-artifacts
      path: dist/

    

debug:
 needs: build
 permissions: write-all
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
  - name: Download Artifacts
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: build-artifacts
      path: dist

  - name: List Files in dist
    run: ls -R dist

  - name: Print Current Directory
    run: pwd

publish:
 needs: build
 permissions: write-all
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: 16
      registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/

  - name: Configure npm registry for GitHub Packages
    run: npm config set registry https://npm.pkg.github.com/

  - name: Download Artifacts
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: build-artifacts
      path: dist

  - name: List Files in dist
    run: ls -R dist

  - name: Changing Directory
    run: |
      cd dist/${{ github.event.inputs.project_name }}

  - name: Publish To Github
    run: |
      cd dist/${{ github.event.inputs.project_name }}
      npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      npm publish --access public
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that both `build`, `debug` and `publish` are run separately. That means `dist` directory created in `build` step cannot be accessed by `publish` step directly.

Looking at your workflow `yaml` file, I don't see a need for separate steps. So you can merge all steps into a single step.

```
name: Angular Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      release_type:
        required: false
        type: string
      project_name:
        description: 'Enter the project name'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
            node-version: 16

      - name: Install Angular CLI
        run: npm install -g @angular/cli
      
      - name: Install dependencies  
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build Angular Project
        run: ng build ${{ inputs.project_name }}

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        run: |
            npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            npm publish --access public
        env:
            NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

On a side note:

1. I have changed `github.events.inputs.*` to `inputs.*`
2. I have removed `cd dist/` command
3. `env` key was formatted incorrectly before

Comment: Hey Robin, there were multiple errors in the file, FYI, each step runs in its own VM, so the whatever happened in the current step doesn't get passed over, one way is to do what you said is have it in one step, the way I did is I upload the artifacts from step 1 which are then downloaded to step 2 and 3, anyway there are other problems in it that Im still working on.

Comment: Yes, looking at your workflow file, I don't see a need for multiple jobs, since its all to publish the github package. In which case, one build suffice. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: No, I really don't need multiple steps, It just looks good.

Comment: Unfortunetly, No. I'll upvote your answer.